# Causal impact: noisy controls lead to strange results

Tags: r, forecasting, causalimpact

I am using R causal impact to measure the effect of a campaign intervention. Doing some tests, I found some consistent but very strange results.

What I did is to generate a time series with weekly seasonality, a baseline, a trend and some noise. After that, I copy the time series and added some extra noise to generate a control. I did not add any increment on post period, so the result I expect is 0 increment. Here is the code:

```
library(CausalImpact)

set.seed(1)
week_aux <- c(3,12,-5,-10,-2,0,3)
test = week_aux + 100 + seq(1,100,1) + rnorm(sd = 2, n= 100)
control <- test + rnorm(sd = 10, n= 100)
data <- cbind(test, control)

matplot(data, type = "l")

pre.period <- c(1, 80)
post.period <- c(81, 100)
impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)

plot(impact)
summary(impact)
```

What I found is that increasing the noise level on the control, I always obtain a positive increment (when I expect zero), up to 10-15%, even when the noise is not so high (similar level to real data I need to model). Here are the images for the generated data and predictions.

[image]
[image]

The increment in this case is 7%, and 0% is not even include in the confidence interval. Any idea about why this could be happening?

Thank you in advance,

Javier